# how to make use of Text Services Framework into .net application

Tags: .net, com, text-services-framework

i want to make use of Com intefaces into my .net application,
but this is related to **Text Services Framework** and i reasearched on this and it was like it only supports COM servers
can anyone help me on this
can i use TSF intefaces into my .net application
and if yes Please tell me how to do it
plzzzzzz :)
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I have the same problem, I am evaluating if i really have to use C++ for doing the job. You can of course create a COM Server in any COM compatible environment, so also in .NET.
I am by far not in any usable state, but I can tell you what I did so far.
First, the msctf.dll only has a header and an IDL file (in Windows SDK 7.0), which has to be modified such that you get a type library (tlb). I used the tlbimp2 from codeplex, it has an xml based rewriting mechanism (that eases the heavy use of pointers in the type library:
Here is my batch file

```
set sdk7=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0
set imported=msctf

rem call "%sdk7%\Bin\SetEnv.cmd"
midl "%sdk7%\Include\%imported%.idl"
rem i copied the tlbimp2 into the sdk bin
tlbimp2 /keyfile:TextService.snk %imported%.tlb /config:msctf.xml
rem tlbimp /keyfile:TextService.snk %imported%.tlb

rem not sure about this
gacutil /u %imported%
gacutil /i %imported%.dll
```

And here my XML rule file (to be expanded of course)
http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/

```XML
<Rules>
  <Rule Name="addlangprofile string 1" Category="Signature">
    <Condition>
      <And>
        <NativeParentFunctionName Operator="Equal" Value="AddLanguageProfile" />
        <NativeParameterIndex Operator="Equal" Value="4" />
      </And>
    </Condition>
    <Action Name="ConvertTo">
      <Parameter Key="Direction" Value="[In]" />
      <Parameter Key="ByRef" Value="False" />
      <Parameter Key="ManagedType" Value="LPArray" />
      <Parameter Key="MarshalAs" Value="(default)" />
      <Parameter Key="Attributes" Value="[SizeParamIndexOffset=+1]" />
    </Action>
  </Rule>
  <Rule Name="addlanguageprofile string2" Category="Signature">
    <Condition>
      <And>
        <NativeParentFunctionName Operator="Equal" Value="AddLanguageProfile" />
        <NativeParameterIndex Operator="Equal" Value="6" />
      </And>
     </Condition>
     <Action Name="ConvertTo">
       <Parameter Key="Direction" Value="[In]" />
       <Parameter Key="ByRef" Value="False" />
       <Parameter Key="ManagedType" Value="LPArray" />
       <Parameter Key="MarshalAs" Value="(default)" />
       <Parameter Key="Attributes" Value="[SizeParamIndexOffset=+1]" />
     </Action>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Name="GUID" Category="Type">
     <Condition>
       <And>
         <NativeName Operator="Equal" Value="GUID" />
       </And>
     </Condition>
     <Action Name="ResolveTo">
       <Parameter Key="AssemblyName" Value="mscorlib" />
       <Parameter Key="ManagedTypeFullName" Value="System.Guid" />
     </Action>
   </Rule>
</Rules>
```

Then I was trying to wrap the interfaces to be more .NET friendly:

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Globalization;

```
using MSCTF;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TextService
{
    public class LanguageProfiles
    {
        private ITfInputProcessorProfiles instance;

        public LanguageProfiles()
        {
            instance = new COMIFace<ITfInputProcessorProfiles>().CreateInstance();
        }

        public CultureInfo CurrentLanguage
        {
            get
            {
                ushort plangid;
                instance.GetCurrentLanguage(out plangid);
                return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(plangid);
            }
            set
            {
                instance.ChangeCurrentLanguage((ushort) value.LCID);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<TF_LANGUAGEPROFILE> ProfilesOfLanguage(CultureInfo culture)
        {
            IEnumTfLanguageProfiles ppenum;
            instance.EnumLanguageProfiles( (ushort) culture.LCID, out ppenum);

            TF_LANGUAGEPROFILE profile;
            uint fetch;
            do
            {
                ppenum.Next(1, out profile, out fetch);
                yield return profile;
            } while (fetch == 1 && profile.fActive != -1);
        }

        public void Register(ref Guid rclsid)
        {
            instance.Register(ref rclsid);
        }

        public void Unregister(ref Guid rclsid)
        {
            instance.Unregister(ref rclsid);
        }

        public void Add(ref Guid rclsid, CultureInfo info, string name, string icon)
        {
            var empty = Guid.Empty;
            instance.AddLanguageProfile(ref empty, (ushort)info.LCID, ref rclsid, name.ToUShortArray(), name.ULength(), icon.ToUShortArray(), icon.ULength(), 0);
        }

        public void Remove(ref Guid rclsid, CultureInfo info)
        {
            instance.RemoveLanguageProfile(ref rclsid, (ushort)info.LCID, ref rclsid);
        }
    }
}
```

The COMIFace class is just a helper to fetch the IIDs from registry, as I only found them in the .c file generated with the IDL compiler. Better would be to parse that file I think, but this works fine too.
The given class works fine, I can register the service with following batch (check if regasm enabled in the C# project Options)

```
set outtype=Debug
set asmname=TextService
cd bin\%outtype%
gacutil /u %asmname%
gacutil /i %asmname%.dll
cd ..\..
```

The problem I had is with all this that its a huge effort and there are many issues that are not worth the pain i think. I am not sure and wish anybody had some guidance.
A point is, one always needs to follow some great site like this: [TSF Aware blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tsfaware/default.aspx)
but then u can write it in C++ anyways. 
One option might be C++/CLR, doing all the COM stuff and registration in C++ and the logic in C#, possible I guess

A here is some test code which shows it basically works:

var profiles = new LanguageProfiles();

```
var ko_KR = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR");

foreach (var profile in profiles.ProfilesOfLanguage(ko_KR))
{
    Console.WriteLine("clsid: " + profile.clsid + " lid: " + CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(profile.langid) + " catid: " + profile.catid + " active: " + profile.fActive + " guidProf: " + profile.guidProfile);
    var id = profile.clsid;
}
```

Comment: hey i can also give u my solution folder, but I dont know where there would be the best place to upload

Comment: @SebastianGodelet, this is great. I have been looking for a solution like this for ages. I'd really like to get my hands on anything you have that can help me with making a wrapper for TSF. Any chance you could stick some code on mediafire or some other place for us who are interested in this kind of development?

Comment: I didn't really work in it any more, i still have the files, but i actually think there could be a new try i guess, i think a combination of this code + MEF would be great, such that you write once the generic COM code bloat and then package individual IME's side by side

Comment: Unfortunately I I dont know C++. It would be really great if all of us interested in a wrapper for .NET could get an open source project going. Probably the best attempt I have seen is from a Japanese guy here: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/NyaRuRu/20040524/p1... and then of course MS seems to have implemented various bits and pieces.... see System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext and System.Windows.Documents.TextStore. And of course bits and pieces all over StackOverflow and other places. It would be great if we could pull these resources together and have something we could all use from within .NET

Comment: Hello @Matt have you done anything about this lately?